# How to customize post excerpt css

Tags: css

I want to customize my post excerpt font and size through CSS.  How would I do this?  I don't think I can add a class, so I'm stumped on how to do this.

///////////////////////////////////

Here is my front-page.php

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: learningwordpress
 */
 
get_header();
 get_template_part ('inc/carousel');
$i = 0;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => 1
);
 
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 
        if( $i %2 == 1 ) {
                   $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>

 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>
            <?php

        }
        else {
         $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-12">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class `customfont` on the p tags around the excerpt, like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: learningwordpress
 */

get_header();
 get_template_part ('inc/carousel');
$i = 0;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => 1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        if( $i %2 == 1 ) {
                   $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="customfont">
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="customfont">
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="customfont">
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>

 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="customfont">
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="customfont">
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="customfont">
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>
            <?php

        }
        else {
         $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-12">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="customfont">
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
get_footer();
```

... and add this CSS:

```
.customfont {font-size: 200%; font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a lot easier than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add CSS class to PHP, then target it?

```
article.post.col-md-4 p, article.post.col-md-12 p { font-size: 1.5em; }
```

You may wish to tweak that to the page(s) it will appear on, assuming the pages have their own class or ID set.

Demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKEdvv